# getting data from wtforms FormField in a Flask route

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I have a problem getting data from a form using it in a route

***forms.py***

```
class Calculator(Form):
    amount = IntegerField('Amount')
    weight = IntegerField('Weight')

class Program(Form):
    cycles = IntegerField('Cycles')
    volume = FormField(Calculator)
```

***app.py***

```
@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def index():
    form = forms.Program()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        values = models.Progression(
            cycles=form.cycles.data,
            amount=form.amount.data,
            weight=form.weight.data
        )
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, values=values)
```

The data for `cycles` comes through just fine  but I am unsure of the syntax for how to access the encapsulated form within my route. The docs say `FormField` will return the data dict of the enclosed form but I can't seem to figure out how to grab that and put it in a variable.

Comment: So what's your problem?  Be specific.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally posted before I finished the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to grab the data I needed using

```
    amount=form.volume.amount.data,
    weight=form.volume.weight.data
```

The real issue came from the fact that the form was not validating when I was using `FormField`. A rookie error I should have checked earlier.
I had to enable CSRF protection by importing it from `flask_wtf` and using `CsrfProtect(app)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the form data does not come through as the attributes of the `Calculator` class. The data is sent as a dictionary from the `volume` attribute.

Test it out with: `print form.volume.data`

(I suggest commenting out your `values` object and just use print statements)

The output should be: `{'amount': foo, 'weight': bar}`

Thanks for teaching me something! I never knew of `FormField`.

Comment: Thanks for that testing tip. It is what lead me to the real cause of my issue.